# Rearranging trigonometry formula

Tags: trigonometry

How do I rearrange this trig formula to make y the subject? I am having trouble to take the $y$ out of the cosine.

$x = \cos(a+y)\times50$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We will have $a + y=\arccos \frac {x}{50} $.

Comment: Sorry @Rohan but i do not know what arccos means...

Comment: See [here](http://www.mathwords.com/c/cosine_inverse.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x = \cos(a+y)\times50$$

Divide both sides by $50$:

$$\frac{x}{50} =\frac{ \cos(a+y)\times50}{50}$$

$$\frac{x}{50}=\cos(a+y)$$

Now take the inverse function of cosinus:

$$a+y=cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{50}\right)$$

Subtract by $a$:

$$y+a-a=cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{50}\right)-a$$

This means that

$$y=cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{50}\right)-a\:.$$

Answer (score 1):

In plain english, $\sin(y) = ?$ is just asking, *"what is the sine of the angle $y $?"*

Similarly, I can ask the question *"what is the angle whose sine is $y $?"*. This seems like a totally legit question, and we represent it as

$$\arcsin(y) = ? $$

The $\arcsin $ functions just asks for the angle that has the given sine. It can be seen as the function that *undoes* what $\sin $ did. Similarly for $\arccos $.

Simplify your expression to

$$\frac{x }{50} = \cos(y + a) $$

That is saying $\frac{x}{50}$ is the cosine of some angle $y+a $. So you ask yourself, what is the angle whose cosine is $\frac{x}{50} $? Well, from the previous sentence we already know it is $y+a $, and the question I worded can be written as

$$\arccos\left(\frac{x}{50}\right) = y+a $$

Which leaves you with an equation you can manipulate in order to isolate $y $.

Comment: so arccos is basically the same thing as cos-1?

Comment: @kimchiboy03 yup